# Why isn't JML implemented as Annotations in Java?

Tags: java, design-by-contract, jml

Contrary to Code Contracts in C#, in JML Code Contracts are just text that's used in the form of comments in the header of a method. Wouldn't it be better to have them exposed as Annotations, then? That way even when compiling the information would persist on the .class's metadata, contrary to comments, that get erased.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I can see JML predates Java annotations by a good number of years.  They could, of course, update it to make use of annotations presumably.

Comment: +1 - The copyright dates on the "draft specification" tech-report are 1998-2006.

Answer (score 8):

There is experimental implementation of JML using Java annotations: 
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jmlspecs/wiki/JML6
Hopefully it will be released in some form in [OpenJML](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jmlspecs/wiki/OpenJml) this year (2010).